# Why can't we use this instance in the static method of extended class?

Tags: java, oop, static

Base class

```
class Basics415 {   

    Basics1 b1 = new Basics1();

    public static void main_hooo(){
        out.println("1234");     
    }

    void main_ho(){

    }

}
```

Extended class

```
public class Basics5 extends Basics415{     

    public static void main(String[] args){

        this.main_hooo();  // this line throws error.
    }

}
```

Why we aren't able to use this instance inside a static method of the extended class?

Comment: There is no instance associated with `this` because it's `static`.

Comment: For future reference: don't name your sample methods `main_hooo` and `main_ho`. That's entirely non-descriptive.

Comment: What would `this` refer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `main` method is static, which means there is no instance of Basic associated with it so `this` won't work. To access the static methods of `Basics415`, you should refer to them explicitly like this:

```
public class Basics5 extends Basics415{
    public static void main(){
        Basics415.main_hooo();
    }
}
```

You could also just do this since `Basic5` extends `Basic415`. Both are acceptable, but your org may have their own style guidelines:

```
public class Basics5 extends Basics415{
    public static void main(){
        main_hooo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that considered really bad form for a static method? And I think you're kind of skipping the point of static methods by writing code that treats it as an instance method...

Comment: @user3580294 I'm not sure what you're getting at. What is really bad form for a static method?

Comment: This answer would be a normal idiom if `main_hooo` were an instance method.  But it isn't.  So creating an instance for the purposes of calling `main_hooo` is pointless.

Comment: Invoking a static method from an instance is considered really bad form, as it's quite misleading.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct way to access a static method. `this` is not static. Instead do `Basic5.main_hooo()`

Comment: In this context, you don't need to specify the type identifier before the invocation.

Comment: While you are correct, it helps illustrate the point it is a method on the class and not the object.

Comment: But if you do want to explicitly use the type identifier, which type identifier should you use? The type where the static method is declared or the type that inherits from it? I've always heard the former.

Comment: The problem is not that `this` is not static: it's that `this` doesn't exist inside a static method. Although frowned upon, it's perfectly valid syntax to access a static method through `this` in a context in which `this` exists (like from inside an instance method)

Answer (score 1):

this and static are opposite to each other, as simple as that.. If you want to use this, use it inside a non-static method.

Answer (score 0):

The main() method must be defined with a String[] parameter if you want it to execute first. Also, main() is a static method (it belongs to the class). There is no instance (this) to refer to.

Use the class name to call it within main:

```
Basics415.main_hooo();  // this line no longer throws an error.
```

Answer (score 0):

For static method not require create an object,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Basics415 b = new Basics415();
        b.main_hooo();// output : 1234
        main_hooo();// output : 1234
        Basics415.main_hooo();// output : 1234
    }
```